Multiple Authentication Schemes switch problem
I have two authentication schemes. First is Custom, second is Social Sign-In. Current (Default) is Custom. When user starts App first time, Custom Scheme is working, but if user Loged In using Social Sign-In (Azure) and goes to login page, he can't log-in using Custom scheme, users gets error "Invalid Login Credentials". In Application Errors report I see component name with Social Sign-In scheme name. If users logouts (Social Sign-In (Azure)), Custom authentication scheme works correctly.
Social Sign-In authentication scheme sets when user clicks button, using redirect to page with request APEX_AUTHENTICATION={Scheme Name}. Switch in Session is enabled for both schemes.
Question is, how to clear that data (set default scheme); set authentication scheme by default when user open login page; how to get user current authentication scheme to indicate that?

The problem has not yet been resolved.
Problem is when user trying to log-in using Social Sign-In (Azure), he was redirected to Microsoft page, doesn't log-in, and can't back to Apex page (to choose another authentication scheme). When user starts application again, application redirects him again to Microsoft page, and again he can't go back to Apex.
How Apex understands and redirect to Microsoft if user is not authenticated? How to solve this problem?
